Fstab does not mount on boot btrfs with subvolumes but "mount -a" does it
It's my first time playing with btrfs so I just followed few tutorials. Drive mount on boot without problem when I don't want to mount subvolumes but it stopped mounting when I added mountpoints for subvolumes. I tried different combinations like subvolumes only but I can't get to mount subvolumes on boot.
This is my current configuration (ideal for me whole drive in /mnt/btrfsd and 2 subvolumes in Home's folders)
LABEL=btrfsd             /mnt/btrfsd         btrfs   rw,exec,nofail,nossd,datasum,compress=zstd:6,autodefrag    
LABEL=btrfsd             /home/user/Music    btrfs   subvolid=257,nofail,nossd,datasum,compress=zst:6,autodefrag    
LABEL=btrfsd             /home/user/Video    btrfs   subvolid=256,nofail,nossd,datasum,compress=zst:6,autodefrag    

It does not mount on boot however it does work with mount -a
My environment is:
OS: Fedora Linux 38 (Xfce) x86_64GPU 
Kernel: 6.5.6-200.fc38.x86_64 
CPU: AMD Ryzen 9 3900X (24) @ 4.000GHz

dnf list | grep btrfs reports:
btrfs-progs.x86_64                                                                       6.5.1-1.fc38                                                     @updates                  
libblockdev-btrfs.x86_64                                                                 2.28-5.fc38                                                      @anaconda                 
btrfs-assistant.x86_64                                                                   1.9-1.fc38                                                       updates                   
btrfs-fuse.x86_64                                                                        0-11.20230119git812c4b7.fc38                                     fedora                    
btrfs-heatmap.noarch                                                                     9-6.fc38                                                         fedora                    
btrfs-heatmap-doc.noarch                                                                 9-6.fc38                                                         fedora                    
btrfs-progs.i686                                                                         6.2.2-1.fc38                                                     fedora                    
btrfs-progs.x86_64                                                                       6.8-1.fc38                                                       updates                   
btrfs-progs-devel.i686                                                                   6.8-1.fc38                                                       updates                   
btrfs-progs-devel.x86_64                                                                 6.8-1.fc38                                                       updates                   
btrfs-sxbackup.noarch                                                                    0.6.11-20.fc38                                                   fedora                    
btrfsd.x86_64                                                                            0.2.0-1.fc38                                                     updates                   
btrfsmaintenance.noarch                                                                  0.5.1-1.fc38                                                     updates                   
golang-github-containerd-btrfs-2-devel.noarch                                            2.0.0-1.fc38                                                     updates                   
golang-github-containerd-btrfs-devel.noarch                                              1.0.0-6.fc38                                                     fedora                    
golang-github-dennwc-btrfs-devel.noarch                                                  0-0.1.20230510gita1f570b.fc38                                    updates                   
libblockdev-btrfs.i686                                                                   2.29-1.fc38                                                      updates                   
libblockdev-btrfs.x86_64                                                                 2.29-1.fc38                                                      updates                   
libblockdev-btrfs-devel.i686                                                             2.29-1.fc38                                                      updates                   
libblockdev-btrfs-devel.x86_64                                                           2.29-1.fc38                                                      updates                   
libbtrfs.i686                                                                            6.8-1.fc38                                                       updates                   
libbtrfs.x86_64                                                                          6.8-1.fc38                                                       updates                   
libbtrfsutil.i686                                                                        6.8-1.fc38                                                       updates                   
libbtrfsutil.x86_64                                                                      6.8-1.fc38                                                       updates                   
ntfs2btrfs.x86_64                                                                        20230501-1.fc38                                                  updates                   
python-btrfs-doc.noarch                                                                  13-8.fc38                                                        fedora                    
python3-btrfs.noarch                                                                     13-8.fc38                                                        fedora                    
python3-btrfsutil.x86_64                                                                 6.8-1.fc38                                                       updates                   
rust-below-btrfs+default-devel.noarch                                                    0.7.1-1.fc38                                                     updates                   
rust-below-btrfs-devel.noarch                                                            0.7.1-1.fc38                                                     updates                   
udisks2-btrfs.x86_64                                                                     2.9.4-7.fc38                                                     updates         

What may be the cause for not mounting on boot?

How do you know it doesn't mount them?  df doesn't necessarily show all the mounts of a disk.  (try df -a instead.)

I know because I don’t see files in folders. @DavidG.

@KamilMaciorowski Yes /home/user is encrypted but systemctl show error after I enter password (it asks for password during boot) for instance I have another drive called “games” that also mount in /home/user/games and it mount after password is provided.

I found problem. In mount flags I misspelled compression flag compress=zst:6. It should be compress=zstd:6.
For some reason it stopped subvolumes from mounting on boot but mount -a still did the trick. I wonder why is that.
